# Kafka AdminUtils.createTopic raises java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I've run into a bizarre issue with Kafka 0.9 failing to create topics through the Java client.

Given the following code -

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import kafka.admin.AdminUtils;
import kafka.utils.ZKStringSerializer$;
import kafka.utils.ZkUtils;

import org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient;
import org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkConnection;

import scala.collection.JavaConversions;

/**
 * This class contains static methods to operate on queues, allowing queue
 * creation and deletion, checking whether queues exist on the broker, and
 * listing all queues on the broker.
 *
 * A topic represents a queue.
 */
public class Topic
{
private static final int DEFAULT_SESSION_TIMEOUT = 10 * 1000;
private static final int DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 8 * 1000;
private static final String ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT = "localhost:2181";

/**
 * Opens a new ZooKeeper client to access the Kafka broker.
 */
private static ZkClient connectToZookeeper ()
{
    return new ZkClient(ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT,
                        DEFAULT_SESSION_TIMEOUT,
                        DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT,
                        ZKStringSerializer$.MODULE$);
}

/**
 * Given a ZooKeeper client instance, accesses the broker and returns
 * information about Kafka's contents.
 *
 * @param zookeeperClient A ZooKeeper client to access broker information
 *                        through.
 */
private static ZkUtils zookeeperUtility (ZkClient zookeeperClient)
{
    boolean isSecureCluster = false;
    return new ZkUtils(zookeeperClient, 
                       new ZkConnection(ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT),
                       isSecureCluster);
}

/**
 * Given its name, checks if a topic exists on the Kafka broker.
 *
 * @param name The name of the topic.
 *
 * @return <code>true</code> if the topic exists on the broker,
 *         <code>false</code> if it doesn't.
 */
public static boolean existsTopic (String name)
{
    ZkClient zkClient = connectToZookeeper();
    ZkUtils zkUtils = zookeeperUtility(zkClient);

    boolean topicExists = AdminUtils.topicExists(zkUtils, name);

    zkClient.close();
    return topicExists;
}

/**
 * Creates new topics, which remain persistent on the Kafka broker.
 *
 * @param names The names of the topic.
 * @param partitions The number of partitions in the topic.
 * @param replication The number of brokers to host the topic.
 */
public static void createTopics (ArrayList<String> names, int partitions, int replication)
{
    ZkClient zkClient = connectToZookeeper();
    ZkUtils zkUtils = zookeeperUtility(zkClient);

    for (String name: names)
    {
        if (existsTopic(name))
            continue;

        AdminUtils.createTopic(zkUtils, name, partitions, replication, new Properties());

    }

    zkClient.close();
}

/**
 * Given its name, deletes a topic on the Kafka broker.
 *
 * @param names The name of the topic.
 */
public static void deleteTopics (ArrayList<String> names)
{
    ZkClient zkClient = connectToZookeeper();
    ZkUtils zkUtils = zookeeperUtility(zkClient);

    for (String name: names)
    {
        if (!existsTopic(name))
            return;

        AdminUtils.deleteTopic(zkUtils, name);
    }

    zkClient.close();
}

/**
 * Lists all topics on the Kafka broker.
 */
public static void listTopics ()
{
    ZkClient zkClient = connectToZookeeper();
    ZkUtils zkUtils = zookeeperUtility(zkClient);

    List<String> brokerTopics = JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(zkUtils.getAllTopics());

    for (String topic: brokerTopics)
        System.out.println(topic);

    zkClient.close();
}
}
```

`deleteTopics()` and `existsTopic()` work perfectly fine, implying everything is up to date and I'm accessing the AdminUtils methods correctly. However, `createTopics()` crashes at run-time with the following exception - `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class`

What could be going on?

Comment: Afair there are two kafka compiles, one for scala 2.10 and one for scala 2.11. Any chance your are mixing this up? Further check that the scala library that you certainly have in the classpath (have you?) has a Product class is contained.

Comment: I'm using Maven to build the project. Adding Scala 2.11 as a dependency fixed the problem right quick. :) Thank you. Write this as an answer and I'm happy to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [two Kafka compiles](http://kafka.apache.org/downloads.html) that require different Scala libraries, either Scala 2.10 or Scala 2.11. If you use one of the two tgz from the download site, you get the right scala library as part of it. If you use maven, you may need to add the dependency separately (I only ever used the tgz, so I don't know the maven dependency.)